# what is the reason to draw the scatterplot matrix for the mcmc sample?

Tags: bayesian, jags, rjags, hierarchical-bayesian, r2jags

I found some bayesian paper try to draw the scatter plot matrix for the parameters.

I just wondering what is the goal to draw this scatter plot matrix?

what is the meaning if I see some linear or nonlinear relationships between samples.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Check for correlated parameters (might need reparameterization), look out for sparsely sampled regions (might either need to drop burn-in or sample longer), check for multimodality (may need reparameterization, symmetry breaking, or mixture modeling), to name a few...